# How to whitelist multipe flashdrive using bash script?

Tags: bash, macos

I created a script that will detect if a Flash drive is inserted. Problem is that it only allow one flash drive, Any idea how can I allow multiple flash drive? udev is not my option because I'm using macos.

```
# !/bin/bash

#Declare Variables
NUM_NOW=`ls -1 /Volumes  | awk '{ cnt++ }END { print cnt }'`
CUR_FD=`find /Volumes -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | cut -d / -f 3`
GET_IP=$(ifconfig en1 | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }')
GET_USR=$(whoami)
VAL_FD=$(ls -l /Volumes | grep -o SAMPLE)

#Checks if the Flash drive is valid
if [[ $VAL_FD = "SAMPLE" ]]; then
  echo "${CUR_FD} IS valid flash drive"
exit 0
elif [[ "$NUM_NOW" -gt "1" ]]; then
  echo "${CUR_FD} IS INSERTED PLEASE REMOVE IT "
  osascript -e 'display notification "Successfully ejected the Flash Drive" with title "Personal Storage was detected"'
  mail -s "Personal Storage was Detected on this IP ${GET_IP}" sample@gmail.com

  hdiutil detach -force /Volumes/${CUR_FD}
fi
```

Thanks. Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: this seems like a sysadmin question (for [su]?) to me ; but then again, are flashdrives and usb drives automatically blacklisted or unwriteable when they are mounted?

Comment: Nope, after they are mounted flashdrive will be ejected , except for the Valid flash drive.

Comment: I think you would be better off using udev rules for this.

Comment: udev is not applicable for macos @RamanSailopal.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem using case statement

```
 # !/bin/bash

#Declare Variables
CUR_FD=`find /Volumes -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | cut -d / -f 3`
GET_IP=$(ifconfig en1 | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }')
GET_USR=$(whoami)

#Check if Variable is empty
[ -z "$CUR_FD" ] && exit 0

case "$CUR_FD" in
  Sample | sample)
          echo "${CUR_FD} IS valid flash drive"
          ;;
          *)
            echo "${CUR_FD} IS INSERTED PLEASE REMOVE IT "
            mail -s "Personal Storage was Detected on this IP ${GET_IP}" machines.sample@gmail.com
            ~/Projects/repo/lib/hipchatNotify.sh verylow note "$GET_USR tried to insert a Personal Storage with this IP: $GET_IP" true
            hdiutil detach -force /Volumes/${CUR_FD}
            osascript -e 'display notification "Successfully ejected the Flash Drive" with title "Personal Storage was detected"'
            ;;
    esac
```